Livewire Component Redirects to /livewire/update one time in Production but Works in Development
Issue:
I'm building a full stack Laravel 11 application with Livewire. In development, everything works fine, but in production, when I make the first component update, it redirects me to GET /livewire/update after making the POST request.
Configuration and Code
Livewire Configuration
<?php

return [

    'class_namespace' => 'App\\Livewire',
    'view_path' => resource_path('views/livewire'),
    'layout' => 'components.layouts.app',
    'lazy_placeholder' => null,
    'temporary_file_upload' => [
        'disk' => null,
        'rules' => null,
        'directory' => null,
        'middleware' => null,
        'preview_mimes' => [
            'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'svg', 'wav', 'mp4',
            'mov', 'avi', 'wmv', 'mp3', 'm4a',
            'jpg', 'jpeg', 'mpga', 'webp', 'wma',
        ],
        'max_upload_time' => 5,
        'cleanup' => true,
    ],
    'render_on_redirect' => false,
    'legacy_model_binding' => false,
    'inject_assets' => true,
    'navigate' => [
        'show_progress_bar' => true,
        'progress_bar_color' => '#2299dd',
    ],
    'inject_morph_markers' => true,
    'pagination_theme' => 'tailwind',
];

Routes
Route::middleware(Lang::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get("/", HomePage::class)->name("home");
    Route::get('route1', Route1::class)->name("who");
    Route::fallback(Error404::class)->name('fallback');
});

app.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <!-- Meta tags, fonts, and styles -->
    @vite('resources/css/app.css')
    @vite('resources/js/app.js')
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/aos@2.3.4/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Favicons -->
</head>

<body class="antialiased bg-third font-cairo">
    {{ $slot }}
    <div class="fixed bottom-10 right-10">
        <a href="https://wa.me/+9054128721369" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/aos@2.3.4/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script>
        AOS.init();
    </script>
</body>
</html>

app.js
import './bootstrap';
import 'alpinejs';

What I've Tried

Alpine.js Initialization:

Ensured Alpine.js is imported correctly.
Tried re-initializing, which showed a warning.


Vite Build:

Verified that Vite built the frontend correctly.


Existing Solutions:

Followed suggestions from this Stack Overflow thread and similar ones to change the update route for Livewire.


Temporary Solution:

Added a GET route for /livewire/update to redirect back, but this reloads the page:

Route::get('livewire/update', function () {
    return redirect()->back();
})->name('update-livewire');



Additional Information
.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

public/index.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

(require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php')->handleRequest(Request::capture());

Network Tab

Checked that Livewire injected the livewire.min.js and it exists.

Question
Why does the first component update in production redirect to GET /livewire/update after making a POST request, and how can I fix this issue without reloading the page?


Did you find any solution about that ? I have the same problem in a filament app when I create a custom page

still no, I made a temp solution, when The user changes the lang, I reload the page with the new lang

I think the problem appearing when the website is hosted in cpanel  hosting panel

this happens after publishing assets and not using dev server

I have the same problem, were you able to fix it?

Route::prefix(LaravelLocalization::setLocale())
->middleware(LaravelLocalizationRoutes::class)
->get('livewire/update', function () {
return redirect()->back();
})->name('update-livewire');
I made that temporary solution. when goining to that route, it goes back. this only happens one for a user, so this is temporary until finding a bux fix. by the way, currently I shifted from livewire to another tech stack
